# Getting an error using keyword throw in java

Tags: java, try-catch

```
import java.io.*;
class A {
     private static final int x = 5;
     private int y;
     A(int z)
     {
       y = z;
     }

     public void f()
     {
        if(y<=x)
        {
           throw(-1);
        }
     }
}


public static void main(String args [])
{
      A a = new A(2);
      try (a.f();)
      catch (int i){
          System.out.println("exception");
          }   
}
```

I am fairly new to java and was trying to learn exception handling. I was just wondering what's wrong with this approach i have because i am getting an error, and how can i fix it?

Comment: You throw exceptions, not numbers. Something like `throw new NullPointerException()` I [googled](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS562US562&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=throw%20exception) for "throw exception" and the  very first link was [How To Throw Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html).

Comment: is it possible for you to show how to fix  this scenario and if you can post as answer i can up vote u also. @Takendarkk

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you run code that gives you errors, post the error message here.

Comment: @user2733436, I believe you are mixing-up the syntax of C++ with java

Comment: @Arvind yes i am is it possible to show fix.

Comment: Why can't you just read the tutorial I linked you to? If we just give you code how will you ever learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code.

1.) `try (a.f();)` syntax is wrong, please see the below.

2.) `throw(-1);` should be throwing exception.

3.) Method should `catch or throws` the exception

```
public class A{
    private static final int x = 5;
    private final int        y;

    A(int z) {
        y = z;
    }

    public void f() throws Exception {
        if (y <= x) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A(2);
        try {
            a.f();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, find the sample code below:

```
class Foo {
  private int bar;
  public void setBar(int bar) {
    if(0 > bar)//raise exception here
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid bar value: " + bar);
    this.bar = bar;//set the bar value
  }
  public int getBar() {
    return bar;
  }
}

class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    try {
      foo.setBar(34);
      System.out.println("bar is: " + foo.getBar());
      foo.setBar(-23);
      System.out.println("next bar is: " + foo.getBar());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {//handle the exception here
       ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i just accepted the other answer  but upvoted yours also.